# GitHub user graph crawler using akka

Tags: scala, mongodb, akka

This code queries the GitHub followers API and stores the graph in a mongodb collection:

```
import java.util.Date
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scalaj.http._


/**
  * Actors are organized roughly like this: https://www.draw.io/#G0B6v1Y7CECqz2eDJGb2hKbEhiLU0
  */
object Fetcher {

  // message definitions
  case class Fetch(val login: String)

  case object WorkAvailable
  case class SetDBWriter(ref: ActorRef)
  case class SetInterpreter(ref: ActorRef)

}

class Fetcher(token: Option[String], responseInterpreter: ActorRef, dBWriter: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import Fetcher._

  def receive = {
    case Fetch(login) => fetchFollowers(login)
    case WorkAvailable => sender ! FetcherManager.WorkRequest
  }

  private def fetchFollowers(login: String): Unit = {
    val unauthorizedRequest = Http(
      s"https://api.github.com/users/$login/followers")
    // send authorized requests when token is available
    val request = token.map { t =>
      unauthorizedRequest.header("Authorization", s"token $t")
    }.getOrElse(unauthorizedRequest)
    val response = Future {
      request.asString
    }

    // Wrap the response in an InterpretResponse message and
    // forward it to the interpreter.
    // Write date to DB to keep track of number of requests made
    response.onComplete {
      case Success(r) => {
        responseInterpreter ! ResponseInterpreter.InterpretResponse(login, r)
        dBWriter ! DBWriter.TrackQuota(new Date())
      }
      case Failure(e) => log.warning(s"Failed to fetch $login: $e")
    }
  }
}

class ResponseInterpreter extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import ResponseInterpreter._
  private var extractor: ActorRef = _
  def receive = {
    case SetExtractor(ref) => extractor = ref
    case InterpretResponse(login, httpResponse) => {
      val body = httpResponse.body
      val followers: Option[JArray] = getFollowers(body)
      followers.map { fs =>
        extractor ! FollowerExtractor.Extract(login, fs)
      }
    }
  }

  def getFollowers(body: String): Option[JArray] = {
    parse(body) match {
      case a: JArray => Some(a)
      case _ => {
        log.warning("Not valid JArray")
        None
      }
    }
  }
}

object ResponseInterpreter {
  case class SetExtractor(ref: ActorRef)
  case class InterpretResponse(login: String, followersResponse: HttpResponse[String])

}

object DBWriter {

  case class Write(login: String, followers: Seq[String])

  case class TrackQuota(date: Date)
  def getClient: MongoClient = {
    val serverAddress = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017)
    val credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("username", "github", "yourpass".toArray)
    val client = MongoClient(serverAddress, List(credential))
    client
  }
}

class DBWriter extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val mongoClient = DBWriter.getClient
  val db = mongoClient("github")
  val coll = db("graph")
  val quota = db("gitquota")
  coll.drop()

  def receive = {
    case DBWriter.Write(login, followers) => followers.foreach { f =>
      coll += DBObject("followed" -> login, "follower" -> f)
    }
    case DBWriter.TrackQuota(date) => quota += DBObject("date" -> date)
  }
}


object FollowerExtractor {
  case class SetDBWriter(ref: ActorRef)
  case class SetManager(ref: ActorRef)
  case class Extract(val login: String, val jsonResponse: JArray)

}


class FollowerExtractor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import FollowerExtractor._

  private var dbWriter: ActorRef = _
  private var manager: ActorRef = _

  def receive = {
    case SetDBWriter(ref) => dbWriter = ref
    case SetManager(ref) => manager = ref
    case Extract(login, followerArray) => {
      val followers = extractFollowers(followerArray)
      manager ! FetcherManager.AddAllToQueue(followers)
      dbWriter ! DBWriter.Write(login, followers)
      followers.foreach { f =>
        log.info(s"$f \t -> \t $login")
      }
    }
  }

  def extractFollowers(followerArray: JArray): Seq[String] = for {
    JObject(follower) <- followerArray
    JField("login", JString(login)) <- follower
  } yield login

}

class FetcherManager extends Actor {
  private var fetchers: ActorRef = _
  val queue = collection.mutable.Queue.empty[String]
  val added = collection.mutable.Set.empty[String]

  def receiveNonEmpty: Actor.Receive = {
    case FetcherManager.AddToQueue(user) => queueOne(user)
    case FetcherManager.AddAllToQueue(users) => users.foreach(queueOne _)
    case FetcherManager.WorkRequest => {
      val user = queue.dequeue()
      if (queue.isEmpty) {
        context.unbecome()
      }
      sender ! Fetcher.Fetch(user)
      added += user
    }
  }

  def receiveEmpty: Actor.Receive = {
    case ref: ActorRef => fetchers = ref
    case FetcherManager.AddToQueue(user) => {
      queueOne(user)
      context.become(receiveNonEmpty)
      notifyFetchers
    }
    case FetcherManager.AddAllToQueue(users) => {
      val newUsers = users.filter(!added(_))
      if (newUsers.nonEmpty) {
        queue ++= newUsers
        context.become(receiveNonEmpty)
        notifyFetchers
      }
    }
    case FetcherManager.WorkRequest =>
  }

  def queueOne(user: String): Unit = {
    if (!added(user)) {
      queue += user
    }
  }

  def notifyFetchers: Unit = {
    fetchers ! Fetcher.WorkAvailable
  }

  def receive = receiveEmpty
}

object FetcherManager {

  case class AddToQueue(user: String)

  case class AddAllToQueue(users: Seq[String])

  case object WorkRequest

}


object GraphDemo extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("fetch_graph")
  val manager: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[FetcherManager]))
  val extractor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[FollowerExtractor]))
  val interpreter: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[ResponseInterpreter]))
  val dbWriter: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[DBWriter]))
  val router: ActorRef = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(4).props(
    Props(classOf[Fetcher], Some("yourtoken"), interpreter, dbWriter)
  ))
  manager ! router
  extractor ! FollowerExtractor.SetDBWriter(dbWriter)
  extractor ! FollowerExtractor.SetManager(manager)
  interpreter ! ResponseInterpreter.SetExtractor(extractor)
  manager ! FetcherManager.AddToQueue("odersky")
  system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5.seconds) {
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.